# How to display images in Show Action of Sonata Admin?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using Symfony 2.8 and Sonata Admin bundle with Sonata ORM.

I use [this](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_image_previews.html#advanced-example-works-with-embedded-admins) to display images in Edit action, and it works fine.

However I want to display image in Show Action, and the instructions doesn't work for  inside configureShowFields of the ImageAdmin

```
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    if($this->hasParentFieldDescription()) { // this Admin is embedded
        // $getter will be something like 'getlogoImage'
        $getter = 'get' . $this->getParentFieldDescription()->getFieldName();

        // get hold of the parent object
        $parent = $this->getParentFieldDescription()->getAdmin()->getSubject();
        if ($parent) {
            $image = $parent->$getter();
        } else {
            $image = null;
        }
    } else {
        $image = $this->getSubject();
    }

    // use $fileFieldOptions so we can add other options to the field
    $fileFieldOptions = array('required' => false);
    if ($image && ($webPath = $image->getWebPath())) {
        // add a 'help' option containing the preview's img tag
        $fileFieldOptions['help'] = '<img src="'.$webPath.'" class="admin-preview" />';
    }

    $showMapper->add('file', 'file', $fileFieldOptions);
}
```

Is it a embed admin

Comment: Unfortunately the link in the question doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look a this bundle : [SonataExtraAdminBundle](https://github.com/picoss/SonataExtraAdminBundle)

You will be able to use a 'image' type on the showMapper.

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ...
        ->add('picture', 'image')
    ;
}
```

You can also use an image prefix or a fixed width and height:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ...
        ->add('picture', 'image', array(
            'prefix' => '/bundles/acme/images/',
            'width' => 75,
            'height' => 75,
        ))
    ;
}
```

Hope this helps